# Question about openai baselines A2C implementation

Tags: asynchronous, process, multiprocessing, reinforcement-learning, openai-api

In A2C algorithm, multiple environments are run in different processes in order to parallelize computation.
In openai baselines implementation, [SubprocVecEnv](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/common/vec_env/subproc_vec_env.py) is the class that creates different processes for the different environments. (You can see almost the same implementation in [stable_baselines](https://github.com/hill-a/stable-baselines/blob/master/stable_baselines/common/vec_env/subproc_vec_env.py)).

The point I don't understand is: why is the argument to the processes a function that returns the environment called `env_fn` and not directly the environment itself called `env`?

In other words, why is L61 like [this](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/common/vec_env/subproc_vec_env.py#L61), and not like this:

`self.ps = [ctx.Process(target=worker, args=(work_remote, remote, CloudpickleWrapper(env)))`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because to create multiple environments you need the function to create them. If you pass the environment itself to it, it's a pass by reference to an instance of the environment and all workers would operate on the same instance.

The function on the other hand allows to create multiple instances so each process can operate on an instance.

Comment: But when we pass an argument to a process, the object is serialized and created in a new address space ? So I don't understand how what you describe can happen. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: After the object is serialized the envs point to the same address as I understand.